# Having problems with webpack build in production

Tags: javascript, webpack, preact

I am working on a project which was initiated by preact-cli.

I have a build script which bundles up my application. The webpack configuration is already defined in preact-cli globally, but I can modify it from preact.config.js.

I checked that there is only one entry point in preact-cli, which is fine for now.

[image: Bundle]

And there is one CommonsChunkPlugin present. It has this config:

[image: CommonsChunkPlugin]

If I build the application normally with this config. I get a big bundle file.

So I started adding my own CommonsChunkPlugin.

Preact provides a way to modify webpack configs. Which is this

My preact.config.js is:

```
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
  let { rule } = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'babel-loader')[0];
  let babelConfig = rule.options;
  babelConfig.plugins.push('transform-decorators-legacy');
  babelConfig.presets.push('flow');
  config.plugins.push(new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(envs.raw));
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(envs.stringified));
  config.plugins.push(new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules));

  rule.options.plugins.push('transform-regenerator');
  rule.options.plugins.push(["transform-runtime", {
    "helpers": false,
    "polyfill": false,
    "regenerator": true
  }]);

  let htmlPlugin = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'HtmlWebpackPlugin')[0].plugin;
    htmlPlugin.options.template = `!!ejs-loader!${path.resolve(__dirname, './template.html')}`;
    htmlPlugin.options.title = "JApp";
    htmlPlugin.options.manifest = Object.assign({}, {
     name: 'JH',
     short_name: 'JApp',
     theme_color: '#007DC5'
   });

  let commonChunksPlugin = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'CommonsChunkPlugin')[0].plugin;
  console.log(commonChunksPlugin);

  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
     name: 'vendor',
     minChunks: ({ resource }) => (
      resource !== undefined &&
      resource.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1
     ),
    }));
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'preact-chunk',
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    minChunks: (m) => m.resource && /preact|preact-compat/.test(m.resource)
   }));
   config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'others-chunk',
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    minChunks: (m) => m.resource && /redux|preact-redux|redux-form|lodash|sane-email-validation|moment|core-decorators|lodash-decorators/.test(m.resource)
   }));
   config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'material-ui-chunk',
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    minChunks: (m) => m.resource && /material-design-lite|preact-mdl/.test(m.resource)
   }));
   config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'manifest',
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    minChunks: Infinity,
   }));
  }
};
```

This configuration gives me all the files that 5 chunks apart rom bundle.js. The manifest file contains the bootstrap file of webpack as expected. I run the application, but I get this error in browser:

```
bundle.9b6d3.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
at bundle.9b6d3.js:1
```

So, I found out that manifest.js file is loading late than bundle.js and all script files have attribute 'defer'. The webpackJsonp definition is present in manifest.js file.

I tried 3 things and before that I checked the 'ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin'  present already in preact-cli. It is this:

[image: ScriptHTMLWebpackPlugin]

The things I tried:

1. Change the default attribute of 'ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin' to async. This way I can make sure that the smallest file executes first, as it will be downloaded first. I wrote this code before adding any plugin in my preact.config.js file:

   ```
   let scriptPlugin = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin')[0].plugin;
   scriptPlugin.options.defaultAttribute = 'async';
   ```

   Now I got the error:

   ```
   bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
       at n (bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:54)
       at Object.<anonymous> (others-chunk.55912d9c.js:12)
       at Object.E/bI (others-chunk.55912d9c.js:1207)
       at n (bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:54)
       at Object.JkW7 (bundle.9b6d3.js:18)
       at n (bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:54)
       at Object.pwNi (entry.js:13)
       at n (bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:54)
       at window.webpackJsonp (bootstrap b7b6d09314cc5ff6d290:25)
       at bundle.9b6d3.js:1
   ```

   The script files are loaded in index.html of build folder as follows:

   ```
   <script defer="defer" src="/bundle.9b6d3.js"></script>
   <script>window.fetch||document.write('<script src="/polyfills.d41d8.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script src="/static/js/manifest.d41d8cd9.js" async></script>
   <script src="/static/js/others-chunk.55912d9c.js" async></script>
   <script src="/static/js/preact-chunk.c2b64323.js" async></script>
   <script src="/static/js/node-static.916ed24c.js" async></script>
   ```
2. Let the attribute still be 'defer', but change the order of loading the files, hoping manifest.js will load earlier than bundle.js. So I wrote this configuration in 'HtmlWebpackPlugin'.

   ```
   htmlPlugin.options.chunksSortMode = function(entry1, entry2) {
       if(entry1.names[0] === "manifest") return -1;
       else return 1;
   }
   ```

   Now I got the error:

   ```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
       at bundle.9b6d3.js:1
   ```

   The index.html file of build folder loaded scripts in this order:

   ```
   <script defer="defer" src="/bundle.9b6d3.js"></script>
   <script>window.fetch||document.write('<script src="/polyfills.d41d8.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script src="/static/js/manifest.d41d8cd9.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script src="/static/js/others-chunk.55912d9c.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script src="/static/js/preact-chunk.c2b64323.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script src="/static/js/node-static.916ed24c.js" defer="defer"></script>
   ```

   **Note: In both the above approaches, my code is not affecting either attribute of position of bundle.js file.**
3. After building through preact-cli, manually change the order of loading scripts, so I put manifest.js above bundle.js. SO it looked like this:

   ```
   <script src="/static/js/manifest.d41d8cd9.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script defer="defer" src="/bundle.9b6d3.js"></script>
   <script>window.fetch||document.write('<script src="/polyfills.d41d8.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script src="/static/js/others-chunk.55912d9c.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script src="/static/js/preact-chunk.c2b64323.js" defer="defer"></script>
   <script src="/static/js/node-static.916ed24c.js" defer="defer"></script>
   ```

   I got this error:

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
       at n (bootstrap 4da816313a3eaaa2f964:54)
       at window.webpackJsonp (bootstrap 4da816313a3eaaa2f964:25)
       at bundle.9b6d3.js:1
   ```

Now I am out of options now and I need help on this.

Comment: some low-hanging fruit, I assume you're already seeing a difference in bundle size when building with `NODE_ENV` equal to "production"?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/959#issuecomment-304947450) for a similar issue in webpack's github, it could be a conflict between `CommonChunksPlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Have you tried setting the `chunksSortMode` option in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to `'dependency'`?

Comment: Will try chunkSortMode

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in preact-cli, the plugin `HtmlWebpackPlugin` has a option: `excludeAssets:[/(polyfills|bundle)(\..*)?\.js$/]`

and the template include this line:

```
<script>window.fetch||document.write('<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks["bundle"].entry %>"><\/script>')</script>
```

So, I write an other templete without above line. Then I modified scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run -s serve || npm run -s dev",
    "build": "preact build --template=src/template.ejs",
    "build-nr": "preact build --no-prerender --template=src/template.ejs",
    "serve": "preact build --template=src/template.ejs && preact serve",
    "dev": "preact watch --template=src/template.ejs",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "jest"
}
```

Then I modified options of HtmlWebpackplgin in file.preact.js:

```
const p = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'HtmlWebpackPlugin')[0].plugin;
p.options.chunksSortMode='dependency'; // I dont't know if it's useful
p.options.excludeAssets: [/(polyfills)(\..*)?\.js$/ ];
```